# QueryResponse.getJobComplete() false means not YET complete or failed?

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to figure out what to do when getJobComplete() returns false. I assume It means that the job failed so I should go ahead and resubmit it but need confirmation and no assumptions!

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api pair jobs.query/jobs.getQueryResults is effectively a wrapper around jobs.insert/jobs.get/tabledata.list.

In both cases you start a query job, wait for it to finish, then read the results from the output table of the query. Queries (and all jobs) run async and can take time, so you need to wait in a poll loop until they are done.

What jobs.query/jobs.getQueryResults provides you is: (1) server-side wait for slightly faster detection of job completion, and (2) the first page of query results are returned when the job completes.

What jobs.insert/jobs.get/tabledata.list provides you is: (1) a consistent way to interact with all types of jobs, and (2) the ability to distinguish between errors in your api request and errors in your query job. If you want to retry api calls that fail due to temporary 5xx errors, it is safe to do that with jobs.get. But you need to take care when calling jobs.getQueryResults since an error in the job is returned as error to the api call.

You can find a Java example of using jobs.query/jobs.getQueryResults in a while loop here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#syncqueries. Notice how the code keeps calling getQueryResults until queryResponse.getJobComplete() is true, then it keeps wiring the pagination token through further calls to getQueryResults() until the entire table is read.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've changed the implementation accordingly. I believe that the documentation is kind of confusing as that call is referred as "synchronous BigQuery query". My understanding is that when it is a synchronous, it should be blocking call until it is done...

Answer (score 2):

As long as `getJobComplete()` returns `false`, this means that the job is still executing. It has neither failed nor suceeded. You must issue another call to `jobs.list` every few seconds as long as the job is not complete.

Once `getJobComplete()` returns `true`, the job is finished, but you must check wether is succeeded or not. To do that, check that `getStatus().getErrorResult()` returns `null`. If it does not return `null` this means the job did not succeed.